# Find Equation for Eclipse / Inverse Parabola in 3D Space Given 2 Points

Tags: math, geometry

In a 3D space (x,y,z), you are given two points with no restrictions.

- Let's say Point 1 = (15,10,-5), Point 2 = (-1, 0, 11)
- An arbitrary point (denoted X in the image) is made by finding the mid-point between point 1 and point 2, in this case (7,5,6), and then y is incremented by 10 which creates a third point
- Point 3 = (7,15,6)
- Attached is an image to better portray these points

The problem is to find an equation that creates the orange line that links the points 1, 2 and 3. The line doesn't necessarily have to link on the bottom, but I assume it is easier to create an ellipse with these points than an inverse parabola.
[image]

Comment: Just for fun: If you say with no restrictions, then without loss of generality you can set `p1 = ( a, 0, b)` and `p2 =  -p1`. But what if `a=0` ? As in the answer by @MBo three points define a circle (or a line) as a special case of an ellipse. BTW without a given baseline a parabola is also not uniquely defined.

Answer (score 1):

It is rather simple to build a circle through these three points (note they must be non-collinear).

Make a plane containing given points, use arbitrary coordinate system in this plane. For example, point `P1` is origin, vector `P2-P1` defines `OX` axis, vector product of `P2-P1` and `P3-P1` defines normal `N`, and `(P2-P1) x N` defines `OY` axis

[Solve](http://www.ambrsoft.com/TrigoCalc/Circle3D.htm) "circle through three points" problem in this plane, find radius and center.

Transform center back into 3D.

Also note that there is infinite number of ellipses and parabolas through three points (until we define additional limitations),